# How to running each method on webbrowser

Tags: c#

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_login_button").InvokeMember("Click"); 
//something that wait about 1 or 2 second before execute next line?               
         webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("nav_settings_link").InvokeMember("Click"); 
         webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("language_change2").InvokeMember("Click");                                   

        }
```

From this code, I tried `Thread.Sleep();` and `Task Delay();` But It's shown nullException...(I think because of they're running while the webpage aren't fully loaded) Anyone can help me out?

Now, I've figured out that the method I want is async method to slow the time while they're still running.

```
    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_login_button").InvokeMember("Click");await Task.Delay(1000);                      webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("nav_settings_link").InvokeMember("Click"); 
await Task.Delay(1000);        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("language_change2").InvokeMember("Click");  }
```

Comment: just put the code in the client-side.

Comment: NullException means that your element is not found. So, you are pretty much on track on what to do next: wait ... longer... until it shows. One way is to do loop to check until the element is not null (with delay of course), then click it.

Comment: @kurakura88 Do you have any idea of code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just an example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;    


Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
int timeout = 60; // 60 seconds
sw.Start(); // Use Restart for the next element, to reset the time to 0 first.
var element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_login_button");
while(element == null && sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < timeout)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_login_button");
}
sw.Stop();
if(element!=null)
{
    element.InvokeMember("Click"); 
}
...
// if success, repeat with similar pattern for the next element
// if you still can't find the element, you'd better quit what you are trying to do
```

Explanation:

1. System.Diagnostics to enable Stopwatch
2. timeout added so that you don't wait forever
3. store the element into variable
4. check the element every 2 seconds
5. if found click and continue next
6. if not.... you probably want to quit what you are doing

Comment: I forget to tell you something, when webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_login_button"); is executed

it's lead to another page. That's why I want something that can wait before executing next line of the code that I've gave from above.